# R understanding {caret} train(tuneLength = ) and SVM methods from {kernlab}

Tags: r, svm, r-caret

Trying to better understand how `train(tuneLength = )` works in `{caret}`. My confusion happened when trying to understand some of the differences between the SVM methods from `{kernlab}` I've reviewed the documentation ([here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/caret.pdf)) and the caret training page ([here](http://topepo.github.io/caret/training.html)).

My toy example was creating five models using the `iris` dataset. Results are [here](http://rpubs.com/mgilbert/SVM_Toy_Example), and reproducible code is [here](https://github.com/jmichaelgilbert/mspaScripts/blob/master/SVM_Toy_Example.R) (they're rather long so I didn't copy and paste them into the post).

From the `{caret}` documentation:

> **tuneLength**
> an integer denoting the amount of granularity in the tuning parameter grid. By default, this argument is the number of levels for each tuning parameters that should be generated by train. If trainControl has the option search = "random", this is the maximum number of tuning parameter combinations that will be generated by the random search. (NOTE: If given, this argument must be named.)

In [this example](http://topepo.github.io/caret/random.html), `trainControl(search = "random")` and `train(tuneLength = 30)`, but there appears to be 67 results, not 30 (the maximum number of tuning parameter combinations)? I tried playing around to see if maybe there were 30 unique `ROC` values, or even `ydim` values, but by my count they're not.

For the toy example, I created the following table:

[image: caret_SVM]

Is there a way to see what's going on "under the hood"? For instance, `M1` (`svmRadial`) and `M3` (`svmRadialSigma`) both take, and are given, the same tune parameters, but based on calling `$results` appear to use them differently?

My understanding of `train(tuneLength = 9)` was that both models would produce results of `sigma` and `C` each with `9 values, 9 times` since `9` is the number of levels for each tuning parameter (the exception being random search)? Similarly, `M4` would be `9^3` since `train(tuneLength = 9)` and there are `3` tuning parameters?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I need to update the package documentation more but the details are spelled on on the [package web page for random search](https://topepo.github.io/caret/random-hyperparameter-search.html):

> The total number of unique combinations is specified by the `tuneLength` option to `train`.

However, this is particularly muddy for SVMs using the RBF kernel. Here is a run down:

- `svmRadial` tunes over cost and uses a single value of `sigma` based on `kernlab`'s `sigest` function. For grid search, `tuneLength` is the number of cost values to test and for random search it is the total number of (cost, `sigma`) pairs to evaluate.
- `svmRadialCost` is the same as `svmRadial` but `sigest` is run inside of each resampling loop. For random, search, it does not tune over `sigma`.
- `svmRadialSigma` with grid search tunes over both cost and `sigma`. In a moment of sub-optimal cognitive performance, I set this up to try at most 6 values of `sigma` during grid search since I felt that cost space needed a wider range. For random search it does the same as `svmRadial`.
- `svmRadialWeight` is the same as `svmRadial` but also considered class weights and is for 2-class problems only.

As for the SOM example on the webpage, well that's a bug. I over-sample the SOM parameter space since there needs to be a filter for `xdim <= ydim & xdim*ydim < nrow(x)`. The bug is from me not keeping the right amount of parameters.

Comment: Hi Max, thanks much for the quick and detailed response. This is very helpful. Using APM in a class along with ESL, PDSwR, and Elder's Ensemble Methods - it's a great text. Michael

Comment: @topepo does `svmRadialWeight` accept the `weights` argument through `train`?